# Scan for available UDP servers

Tags: python, python-3.x, udp

I want to design a Python UDP devices scanner, as I which to scan my devices which work over UDP without specifying any IPs or ports.

I can't find anything on the web on how to do this. They always start from a fixed IP address. Does anyone can give me a hint on how to achieve this?

My best attempts whas the following, but it doesn't find my UDP server:

```
from netifaces import interfaces, ifaddresses, AF_INET
def ip4_addresses():
    ip_list = []
    for interface in interfaces():
        curr_ifaddresses = ifaddresses(interface)
        if AF_INET in curr_ifaddresses:
            for link in curr_ifaddresses[AF_INET]:
                ip_list.append(link['addr'])
    return ip_list

print(ip4_addresses())
```

Thanks very much,
DTake

Comment: maybe have a look at what established port scanners do for UDP?  e.g. https://nmap.org/book/scan-methods-udp-scan.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is a normal way : using a groupcast/multicast and the message contains it's own ip/portr for communication later. When server receive and check it, then connect to it.

Comment: Sorry, can you give further information? Couldn't understand.

Comment: You can look at this protocol as an example: http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0014.html. And there are some open source project you can use in github like libtorrent.